# Phantom photos stuck on my iPhone that I can't delete?

Tags: iphone, itunes, photos

According to iTunes:

[image]

According to my phone:

[image]

But also:

[image]

What's going on? :-/

I look into my DCIM folder on my iPhone through Windows Explorer and it's empty, too.

---

Update: I have no photo syncing going on in iTunes, nor do I have any "recently deleted" items on my iPhone

[image]

Comment: Did you check in Recently Deleted?

Comment: after updated question… I'd try 1) reboot or 2) sync/backup/restore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the date of your phone a few months back. These phantom photos should now show up in "Recently Deleted" section on iOS photos. Delete them from there, and then set the date back to the present.

Comment: This does not work 100%, I have the same issue and setting date does not fix it.

Comment: Doesnt work for me either.

Answer (score 2):

Since iTunes is showing the photos on there, are you not perhaps syncing photos from your PC? Your screenshot shows you looking at your Camera Roll which is indeed empty, but if you tap the `< Albums` button (visible at the top of your screenshot), does it show any more albums? The other option, as @Tetsujin suggested, is that the photos are still in your "Recently Deleted" album, which you will see when you tap `< Albums`.

Only photos taken on your device will show up in the DCIM folder on your PC, the same as a DCIM folder from any digital camera. Windows doesn't have access to the other directory where synced photos are stored so you won't see them in Windows Explorer.

To remove photos synced via iTunes:

1. Launch iTunes and connect your device.
2. Select your device in the iTunes window.
3. Select the "Photos" tab in the sidebar (iTunes 12) or under the main ribbon (iTunes < 12).
4. Deselect the option to sync photos or a folder to your device.

Comment: Sadly this isn't the answer. (See my updated question.) Thanks, though.

Answer (score -2):

Set the date back 6 months or more if necessary, and keep deleting the "deleted photos" until there are no more deleted photos available.  This recovered 25GB -gigabytes- from my phone.

Answer (score -3):

move the Date on your phone earlier by 1,2,3 months and find the phantom photos in the Recently Deleted Folder. Next, delete the photos manually from the Recently Deleted Folder and then reset to your current date

Comment: This is just a repeat of what another user already wrote.