# My iPad camera roll says it is using 7.5 gb after all pics have been deleted for weeks

Tags: iphone, ipad, photos, memory, space

Please help me. I have deleted apps and photos to get memory on my iPad, and it still says I have 0gb left. It has been a couple of weeks. All photos have been deleted from the 'recently deleted' album.  It says the camera roll is using 7.5gb, when there are no photos. It's affecting my iPad speed. I've tried rebooting my iPad. I can't install anything, as my memory is used up. It has 16gb, and I think it's an iPad 2.

Note: I don't have a Macpro, MacBook, iPhone, iPod, iMac or anything else made by Apple.

Comment: Reboot, or sync the phone to iTunes - that ought to update the usage; it's not instantaneous.

Comment: I've rebooted many times and it is synced to iTunes as I have music on and it's ipad but cheers got anything else and it's my photos

Comment: Check the 'deleted' album. iOS allows you to recover pictures.

Comment: Nothing in 'deleted' album

Comment: Check this post, http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175608/phantom-photos-stuck-on-my-iphone-that-i-cant-delete/175624#175624, and try the solution presented in the accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you very much as I set the date back got images back deleted them and have my memory back oh god you don't know happy I am now I can type without lag

Comment: Please go ahead and make an answer how you solved things even if it just took time to clean itself up. That way you can accept your answer and people can know you don't still need more ideas.

Answer (score 5):

Plug your iPad into iTunes and verify that there are no folders of photos from your computer that are being synced onto your iPad, it is possible that although you have deleted all of your photos that you took on your phone (i.e. the ones in the camera roll) you could still be syncing a folder of photos from your computer.

This [link from the Apple website](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201313) should have all the information you need about how to check that if you are unaware.

Answer (score 2):

Although I deleted my photos on my iPad mini the storage showed no reduction until I looked in "recently deleted". I emptied the "recently deleted" and regained the space used by the deleted photos.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to connecting to iTunes (which is a great idea to back things up since when you run out of space, bad things can happen) you can log into iCloud.com and verify that your cloud storage and deleted items match what the device is telling you.

If there are items to come down from the cloud, you may have to clean it up there if the device has no room to move. It could be just wedged.

I would go to usage under the settings app and delete some third party apps that use a lot of storage but that you can recover (say games that have saved state elsewhere online or don't need saved state) and then power down the device.

Clean things up online using a computer and then plug into iTunes if you can borrow a PC or Mac from a friend (set up a new user account - don't connect to their iTunes and mess up syncing further).

Worst case, ask a follow on question detailing the usage stats and iOS version and we'll see what to do next.

Answer (score -1):

go to photos, then albums and the bottom listed one will be RECENTLY DELETED.

In there will be your deleted photos, select those, select all and then delete. Your space will be recovered.

Comment: the OP already said that had been done.