# How to delete photos to free up space?

Tags: iphone

My wife's iphone is full. I decided to free up some space by removing the photos. I connected iphone to PC and copied over complete photo collection. Then I disconnected the device and started removing each single photo by hand! Well, because you just can't **select all** and **remove** photos from your device in 2016 unless it is Android, Windows or Blackberry phone. So, after spending enough time to delete 1.5k photos by hand, I removed them from "recently deleted" folder only to see that the **available space is 0 bytes**. I restarted the phone. Tried to take a photo, no luck. The iphone refuses to take a picture because there is not enough space on the device. This is peculiar because I have zero photos according to "camera roll". So, now, I can't neither install an new app nor take photos, ffs Carl!

I am literally laughing while writing this because the question is so dumb simple I've never expected to ask. How to **actually remove** the photos from iphone to free some space?

This is iphone-4 with iOS 9.3.5.
Some screenshots.

[image] [image]

[image] 
[image]

Comment: Which version of iOS is running on the phone? Also, can you add a screenshot of the memory usage (somewhere in Settings -> General, depends on the iOS version)?

Comment: Can you show us what it says if you click on "Manage Storage" under "Storage"?

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan, it says that Photos & Camera still hold 3.4GB :)

Comment: Try setting the date way back (http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175608/phantom-photos-stuck-on-my-iphone-that-i-cant-delete/176800#176800)

Comment: No, setting time back does not work.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/263732/photos-taking-up-storage-on-iphone-when-i-have-no-photos Duplicate?

Comment: Correct, a duplicate which is also not resolved.

Comment: If this is indeed a duplicate of that other question, the correct way to bring attention there is to add a [bounty](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) to that question and not open a new one.

Comment: I managed to solve my issue by using **iExplorer** in demo mode. I followed the following youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dGaR9hglCJ0

Answer (score 0):

Can you also click on `Photos & Camera` in Storage, and show us what it says there?

The photo files may be from Photo Stream. The fast way to take care of that would be to turn of Photo Stream on the iPhone, but keep in mind that will prevent future pictures from being sent to Photo Stream.

[image]

Comment: there are no photos in photo stream

Comment: Tap on the Photos & Camera so we can see the breakdown of space usage in that category -- it may help us track down the 3.4 GB better.